# Error: .plugins[3] may only be a two-tuple or three-tuple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, storybook

I'm trying to get `storybookJs` to work, when i run the command `npm run storybook` i get this error:

```
Error: .plugins[3] may only be a two-tuple or three-tuple
```

This is my file .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015-node5"],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    [
      "module-alias",
        {
          "src": "./src/screens",
          "expose": "screens"
        },
        {
          "src": "./config",
          "expose": "config"
        },
        {
          "src": "./src/shared",
          "expose": "shared"
        },
        {
          "src": "./package.json",
          "expose": "package"
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

babel packages version

- "@babel/core": "^7.12.0",
- "babel": "^6.23.0",
- "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
- "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
- "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
- "babel-plugin-module-alias": "^1.6.0",
- "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
- "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
- "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
- "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
- "babel-preset-es2015-node5": "^1.2.0",
- "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a set of `[]`, for examples, see [the docs for the plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-alias).

```
[
  "module-alias",
    {
      "src": "./src/screens",
      "expose": "screens"
    },
    {
      "src": "./config",
      "expose": "config"
    },
    {
      "src": "./src/shared",
      "expose": "shared"
    },
    {
      "src": "./package.json",
      "expose": "package"
    }
]
```

should be

```
[
  "module-alias", [
    {
      "src": "./src/screens",
      "expose": "screens"
    },
    {
      "src": "./config",
      "expose": "config"
    },
    {
      "src": "./src/shared",
      "expose": "shared"
    },
    {
      "src": "./package.json",
      "expose": "package"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: i took them out because i had this error `Error: .plugins[3][1] must be an object, false, or undefined`

Comment: Then this whole config is wrong because your config is for Babel 6.x and you are using Babel 7.x

Comment: `"@babel/core": "^7.12.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^18.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-module-alias": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-node5": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"`

Comment: `@babel/core` is 7.x and `babel` is 6.x